# How to write $x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus

How can I convert this equation $x^2 + (y-2)^2 = 4$ into polar coordinates? I know that $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$. I tried plugging those knowns in but i felt stuck.

Comment: Just do the algebra and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$x^2+(y-2)^2 =4 \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2-4y+4=4 \Leftrightarrow x^2+y^2=4y \\ \Leftrightarrow r^2=4r\sin\theta \Leftrightarrow r=4\sin \theta$$

Comment: Thank you so so much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

$$r^2\cos^2(\theta) + r^2\sin^2(\theta) - 4r\sin(\theta) + 4 = 4$$

$$r^2(\cos^2(\theta) + \sin^2(\theta)) - 4r\sin(\theta) = 0$$

$$r = 4\sin(\theta)$$